# Powershell Get-Content to Messagebox keep newlines

Tags: powershell, newline, messagebox

I'm using powershell to show users a messagebox.
The title and text for the messagebox are extracted from a text file:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information
$MessageBody = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\text_body.txt"
$MessageTitle = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\text_title.txt"
$MessageBody
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
```

The text in the text_body.txt contains CariageReturns / LineFeeds. When I output the variable $MessageBody to the console I see the CR / LFs. When I look at the messagebox, all CR / LFs are gone. All text is in one big line.

If I would declare all the text to a variable within the powershell script and parse that variable to the messagebox my CR / LFs are preserved...

How can I preserve the CR / LFs when I use the get-content command and parse the text to a messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to preserve the new lines / CR / LFs by parsing the text file to the "Out-String" command. My script looks like this now:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information
$MessageBody = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\text_body.txt" | Out-String
$MessageTitle = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\text_title.txt"
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
```

Comment: `Get-Content` spilts the file being read at newlines resulting in an array of strings. If you use `Get-Content  -Raw file.txt`instead   the file will be read as a single string preserving the newlines.